# Changing Tab Layout from Words to Icons

Tags: java, android

I'm still for ever learning code but need some help with this one...

I wanted to change the words on my Tab view to icons,

How would I do that?

This is my Main.java

```
public class Main extends ActionBarActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;
    ViewPager pager;
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
    SlidingTabLayout tabs;
    CharSequence Titles[] = {"Home", "Events", "Bluetooth Chat"};
    int Numboftabs = 3;      

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);

        // Creating The Toolbar and setting it as the Toolbar for the activity.

        // Creating The ViewPagerAdapter and Passing Fragment Manager, Titles fot the Tabs and Number Of Tabs.
        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), Titles, Numboftabs);

        // Assigning ViewPager View and setting the adapter.
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Assiging the Sliding Tab Layout View.
        tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true); // To make the Tabs Fixed set this true, This makes the tabs Space Evenly in Available width

        // Setting Custom Color for the Scroll bar indicator of the Tab View
        tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
            @Override
            public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
                return getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor);
            }
        });

        // Setting the ViewPager For the SlidingTabsLayout.
        tabs.setViewPager(pager);
        final Button b = new Button(Main.this);
        b.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_pressed));
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void Main2(View view)    {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Main2.class));
    }

    public void Bluetooth(View view)    {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Main.this.finish();
    }
}
```

This is my ViewPagerAdapter.Java

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    CharSequence Titles[]; // This will Store the Titles of the Tabs which are Going to be passed when ViewPagerAdapter is created
    int NumbOfTabs; // Store the number of tabs, this will also be passed when the ViewPagerAdapter is created

    // Build a Constructor and assign the passed Values to appropriate values in the class
    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,CharSequence mTitles[], int mNumbOfTabsumb) {
        super(fm);

        this.Titles = mTitles;
        this.NumbOfTabs = mNumbOfTabsumb;
    }

    //This method return the fragment for the every position in the View Pager
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                return new Tab1();
            case 1:
                return new Tab2();
            case 2:
                return new Tab4();
        }
        return null;
   }

    // This method returns the titles for the Tabs in the Tab Strip
   @Override
   public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return Titles[position];
   }

    // This method returns the number of tabs for the tabs Strip
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NumbOfTabs;
    }
}
```

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ImageSpan & SpannableString to show an Icon instead of Text.

First create an array of Drawable source,

```
int tabIcons[] = {R.drawable.ic_tab_home,
            R.drawable.ic_tab_job,
            R.drawable.ic_tab_map,
            R.drawable.ic_tab_comments
    };
```

Then Override getPageTitle() like this,

```
 @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
         Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(tabIcons[position]);
                    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, 56, 56);
                    ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(drawable);
                    SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(" ");
                    spannableString.setSpan(imageSpan, 0, spannableString.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                    return spannableString;
    }
```

Comment: I get a error when i put in this code:

Error:(50, 43) error: method getDrawable in class WallpaperManager cannot be applied to given types;
required: no arguments
found: int
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: Are you using the drawable source id inside the tabIcons[] array ? Make sure you put exactly the same number of drawable for your tabs. e.g for 3 tabs use 3 drawable id. Also make sure all drawable files exists in your drawable folder.

Comment: Yeah I am, if I create a method for getResources() I get the above error, if I don't create a method i get this error
Error:(48, 29) error: cannot find symbol method getResources()

Comment: Don't create a method called getResources(), use the default getResources(). Try getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(tabIcons[position]);

Comment: For some reason its not using the default, 
getResources() is in RED and when I press Alt and Enter it gives me the options to "Create Getter" "Create property" and "Create method 'getResources', If I put your code into the Main.Java it finds the default but in my ViewPagerAdapter it doesn't recognize it.